# Issue importing Python tempfile module

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am trying to create tempfile but my python versions do not allow me to proceed and give the following complaints. 
Do I need to upgrade this version to use tempfile module. 
Thanks

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan  9 2013, 06:47:03) [GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tempfile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "tempfile.py", line 2, in ?
    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NamedTemporaryFile'
```

Answer (score 8):

You are importing a **local** file. You have a file named `tempfile.py` in your local directory that masks the global module. `import tempfile` imports that file, not the standard library module.

Use `print tempfile.__file__` to locate that file if you cannot find it. Rename that file to something else.

The [Python 2.4 `tempfile` module](http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/module-tempfile.html) supports `NamedTemporaryFile` without upgrading.